# \w is not abbreviating $HOME as ~

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm SSHing into my schools linux servers, and My PS1 is currently set to:

```
PS1="$USER@${HOSTNAME%%.*} (\w) % "
```

and when I first connect my prompt correctly shows:

```
myusername@servername (~) %
```

but once I cd to any other directory, $HOME is no longer abbreviated as ~. Even if I cd back to ~, $HOME is still expanded in the directory. Isn't \w always supposed to abbreviate?

Thanks for any help/tips.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? In `4.3.48`, `\w` is abbreviating `$HOME` as `~`, even after I cd to a different directory.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I have the opposite problem: at the first connection, the full home (absolute path) is expanded, but then if I do `cd`, it becomes a tilde. In my case, there is a difference between the `$HOME` value, which is a _symlink_ to an absolute path. Could you check this: `cd ~`, and check if there is a difference between the output of `pwd` and `pwd -P` ?

Answer (score -1):

I run into a similar problem with one user in my systems. Additionally, she had problems to change password, but root was able to change it (I run debian stretch).
For some unknown reason her account was created with this problem, yet everything else worked fine. Solution:
sudo usermod -d /home/User_Directory User_Name

and both problems were solved.